# Finding the maximum property under a value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list of objects, each with its properties.
I am trying to find a specific object in this list with this .find although I can't figure out how to find the maximum value of one of it's properties under a certain value.

```
let x = this.state.pricing_adjustments_view.filter((e) => {
    return e.location_id === this.state.selectedLocation,
    e.car_model_id === this.state.selectedCar,
    moment(e.calendar_day).isSame(this.state.from, "day"),
    _.max(e.minimum_duration) <= duration
  })
```

Here it's the e.minimum_duration. I want to find the biggest value, but that is under "duration"
I am trying it with "lodash", here represented by the "_".
I am open to other possibilities.

this.state.pricing_adjustments_view is an array of objects, and you could say that for each object, the "UNIQUE" key is its "location_id", "car_model_id", "calendar_day" and "minimum_duration".

So there are several objects that are the same if we only consider "location_id", "car_model_id", "calendar_day", and then they have different "minimum_duration". I need to get the one that has the highest "minimum_duration".

Comment: Pls provide some example of input and expected output.

Comment: return with a check and comma operator? either some code is missing or it makes no sense.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's how i usually do it, .filter((e) => {return e.thing = thing, e.thing = thing}) and it works

Comment: I'm not certain there is enough detail here for us to help you, consider reading up on [Minimal, Complete, Verifieable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: for example `e.location_id === this.state.selectedLocation` has nothing to do with the rest. it is not use in an `if` clause, nor as expression as return value or as part of a ternary.

Comment: @NitishNarang this.state.pricing_adjustments_view is an array of objects. Each object has several properties, one of them being minimum_duration. For each object identified by a location, car_model, and calendar_day there are several minimum durations. I want to find the object that has the highest minimum duration, but that is under the value of the "duration" variable which is a positive integer

Comment: @NinaScholz the thing is if I remove the last condition (_.max(e.minimum_duration) <= duration) it works perfectly. So it does work, what doesn't work is my conditional for minimum_duration

Comment: So based on your edit, you first need to think about how to group the objects by "location_id", "car_model_id", "calendar_day". Then within those groups you will look for the max value. Until you've grouped it, you won't be able to filter. It would **really** help you get good answers if you posted some sample data rather than making use read between the lines of your description.

Comment: @Valenti It would be more clear to all of us if you just provide input data, and expected output data in your question. Sometimes code explains better than words :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

You say it's the `minimum_duration` that interests you. In order to find the biggest (or smallest..) It's simple to just **order** `pricing_adjustments_view` **by** `minimum_duration` and take it's highest value.

So you can basically do following using `lodash` lib.

```js
// sort dataa..
let sorted = _.sortBy(this.state.pricing_adjustments_view, 'minimum_duration');

// take last in list!
let has_highest_minimum_duration = sorted[sorted.length-1];
```